# Bash equivalent for aws s3 boto's set contents_from_string is required

Tags: string, bash, amazon-s3, upload, boto

I am writing bash script to upload key into a bucket.
I want to create a key dynamically and upload its contents, which is obtained from processing the list.
In boto ,I can do this using :

```
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'foobar'
k.set_contents_from_string('This is a test of S3')
```

How can I achieve the same in aws s3 using bash script?
The aws s3 api method put object has --body parameter which accepts only blob values and does not allow me to upload string.

Comment: Can you clearly explain your requirement in `bash`? with an input and a proper expected output?

Comment: @Inian : so i would be running the script as follows filename.sh username pwd email.From this i want to create a key whose name is username and value of the key to be uploaded will contain pwd email and other user data.

Comment: So you want to create an variable name same as username and a string with password, email and other information? Can you provide a sample example contents of the information you are looking for?

Comment: If you read the example, you will notice it is expecting a serialize file object. Why don't you pipe the output to a file or pipeline? 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html